# Partitions on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

When I installed Ubuntu I created two partitions: \usr and \home, respectively of 20 GB and 180 GB. Now Ubuntu says me that the space to install softwares is exhausting (\usr has only 800 MB of free space).

How can I exploit the \home partition by means of its 180 GB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the forward slash "/" and not the back slash "\" is the character for specifying a directory in Linux.  The backslash is a special character that will give special attributes to the next character that following it.

As far as using the 180G area, you can find a directory that has content that you might want to consider adding a symbolic link to space on the /home partition.

You can check what is using a lot of your space in your /usr partition with this command (or a variation there off):

```
$ cd /usr
$ du -sh $(ls)
```

Some of the directories will require elevated access to scan.  You can add `sudo` to check the size of those folders.

```
$ sudo du -sh $(ls)
```

If you have folders that have spaces you can check those folders by temporarily modifying the field separator with this variation of the command.

```
$ STOREIFS=$IFS && IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && sudo du -sh $(ls);IFS=$STOREIFS
```

Now once you see the folder that is taking up all your space you can move the files to a directory on your /home folder and make a symbolic link to it as such (for instance if `/games` is the oversize folder).

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/games
$ sudo cp -pvau /usr/games /home/
$ sudo mv /usr/games /usr/games.old
$ sudo ln -s /home/games /usr/games
```

Now after you have verified that the new physical location of your `/usr/games` folder works you can delete the /usr/games.old folder.

I used `/usr/games` as an example.  You could do that with any folder from the /usr directory.

Comment: It works. I found /usr/local directory. The only strange thing is that a new /home/local directory has not been created. Files and directories in the /usr/local have been directly copied in the /home directory.

Comment: @Alessandro What did you use for the `cp` parameter?  Did you use `-pvau`?  The `-a` is what will create the directories...(copy directories recursively).